# How to send HTTP request and get json data back using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, request, observable

When a user clicks "Get HTTP Data" button the `getData()` method defined in the `app.component` calls `http` service's `getData()` method that is supposed to return the `json` data. But instead it returns the `ZoneAwarePromise` object:

[image]

```
export class HttpService {
  jsonFile = '../assets/products.json';

  getData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonFile)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(">>> .then got response:", response);
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Here is the link to the Stackblitz project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ukgwct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhttp.service.ts

How to fix this issue and make the http service to return the json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the fixed the issue in the stackblitz link. - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmq58v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The problem is, in the service, you do not subscribe to observables or listen to the promises using then or cathErrors during the creation( this is your case )

Rather, you should subscribe to the service in the component, where you are injecting it.

Comment: I can't see any changes on Stackblitz project. What script did you edit?

Comment: I created a fork and then added the changes. Check this link -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmq58v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmq58v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html