# How to return array from async function in Angular 8 or 9

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

Clicking the `Click Me` button calls the `getDataAsObservable` method defined in `http.service.ts` script:

```
export class HttpService {
  jsonFile = '../assets/products.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getDataAsObservable(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonFile)
  }
}
```

After receiving the `observable` from the `http` service the `requestDataAndWait` method defined in the `app.component.ts` script assigns the received `response` to the local variable `data` and returns it back to the `onClick` method. But instead of receiving the array data the `onClick` method gets `ZoneAwarePromise` object:

[image]

```
  async requestDataAndWait() {    
    let data = [];
    await this.http.getDataAsObservable()
      .toPromise().then(response => {data=response;} );
    return data
  }
```

Here is the link to the Stackblitz project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bygaut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

How to make the `requestDataAndWait` return the `data` array instead of the `ZoneAwarePromise` object?

Comment: Please see the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. `async` functions **always** return a promise (that's the whole *point* of them) and you can't get around asynchronous control flow by assuming it doesn't exist. It seems like you've been told this twice already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62295405/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62296092/3001761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first change the Service class to return a response like this

```
getDataAsObservable(): Promise<any> {
 return this.http.get(this.jsonFile).toPromise()
}
```

Then change your component class like this

```
async onClick() {
 let result = await this.requestDataAndWait();
 console.log("result:", result);
}

async requestDataAndWait() {  
 return await this.http.getDataAsObservable();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296092/how-to-make-synchronous-http-request-in-angular-8-or-9-make-a-request-and-wait#comment110200905_62296464 (in this case it's `val` that's the pointless assignment). Also `getDataAsObservable` isn't a great name for a function that returns a promise...

Comment: Yes correct. But I wanted him to understand quickly. instead of refactoring. I will adjust a bit. Thanks a lot for the comment!